# Include External CSS with javascript beofre title tag

Tags: javascript

I want to include external CSS with javascript before the title tag. How can I do that?

My HTML code looks like below.

```
<html lang='en_us'>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="custom/include/toast/jquery.toast.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="build/css/intlTelInput.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                                
    <title>LOKESH</title>
```

I have used the below code but it does not fulfill my requirement.

```
let title = document.getElementById('title');
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = 'modules/Treat/css/app.css';
document.title.appendBefore(link);
```

Comment: Why specifically _before_ the `title` element? Why not just append it to `head`?

Comment: @Yousaf because order matters in this case. So I want to include it before the title tag. Or I want to insert after build/css/intlTelInput.css

Comment: 1. `title` element doesn't have a `title` id; `document.getElementById('title')` ----> `document.querySelector('title')` 2. There is no `appendBefore` method; `document.title.appendBefore(link)` ----> `title.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", link)` or `document.insertBefore(link, title)`

Comment: Why does the order matter?

Answer (score 1):

Comments already pointed out every error. Here is the fixed code:

```
let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
let title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];

let link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = 'modules/Treat/css/app.css';

head.insertBefore(link, title);
```